# How do i use to the input value in the form in the where clause of my model using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Want to use the luggage_id in the form input type="text" name="luggage_id" as a where clause in my model to update a row 'status' in 'consignment' table

**My view**

```
<form action='<?php echo site_url('clientaccount_ctrl/confirm_load_pickup'); ?>' method='post' name='process'>

          <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="luggage_id" placeholder="Driver ID">

          </div>


          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">

          <button type="submit" class="btn bg-blue btn-flat margin">CONFIRM PICKUP</button> 


</form>
```

**My Controller**

```
 public function confirm_load_pickup(){

                            $this->load->model('Clientaccount_model');
                            $this->Clientaccount_model->confirm_load_pickup();
                            redirect('clientaccount_ctrl');

  }
```

**My Model**

```
  public function confirm_load_pickup(){

                        $luggage_id = $this->input->post('luggage_id');
                        $data['status']=3;
                        $this->db->where('luggage_id',$luggage_id);
                        $query=$this->db->update('consignment',$data);
                        return $query;          
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an active code ignighter developer, but basic experience with several php mvc frameworks leads me to believe that the model doesn't extend a way to process form data as a controller would.

In the controller scope, $this refers to the controller.
In the model scope, $this refers to the model.

Assuming the model scope doesn't explicitly handle the controller scope and post / get methods, it would be unable to process the variable.

So, I would define the input in the controller and inject it into the model

**Controller**

```
public function confirm_load_pickup(){
    $luggage_id = $this->input->post('luggage_id');
    $this->load->model('Clientaccount_model');
    $this->Clientaccount_model->confirm_load_pickup($luggage_id);
    redirect('clientaccount_ctrl');
}
```

**Model**

```
public function confirm_load_pickup($luggage_id){
    $data['status']=3;
    $this->db->where('luggage_id',$luggage_id);
    $query=$this->db->update('consignment',$data);
    return $query;          
}
```

Comment: FYI - you are wrong, you can use $this->input->post in a model. And form validation, etc. Whether you want/need to or not usually gets down to fat vs thin controllers, libraries vs models, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Im not a CI developer so I was unaware, just tried to help based on my other framework experience. It is totally possible to extend response / request data in models, but it generally entails loading that particular namespace into scope. If ci does this automatically, it was a learning experience for the OP as well as myself. Thank you.